# DropDown selected Value not visible in browser

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver

In my case one page contains Drop-down control. Which is actually Input Tag of Html code, using ExtJs it's value can be set.
Now I trying to automate this control value selection using webDriver. Following is my script that execute this code. Default value of control is 'Equal'.

[Here is my Html code and control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0SmV.png)

Now I trying to automate this control value selection using webDriver. Following is my script that I use.

```
@Test(priority=4, dependsOnMethods = {"GoToAssesssmentMetaDataSearch"},alwaysRun = true)
public void SelectSearchCriteriaAssesssmentMetaDataSearch(){
      mDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
      JavascriptExecutor jse  = (JavascriptExecutor)mDriver;
      ((JavascriptExecutor)mDriver).executeAsyncScript("jQuery('.x-form-field.x-form-text.x-form-text-default.x-form-focus.x-field-form-focus.x-field-default-form-focus').val('In');");
      mDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This script run Successfully and test get passed.But in GUI window (IntPut Tag) don't showing Actual value that is set run time in script i.e 'In' in this case. When I check the same jQuery command in WenDriver Browser instance's console window it shows selected value. 
Can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#combobox-2006-bodyE1")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#combobox-2006-inputE1")).sendKeys("In");
```

let me know if this helps..

Note give some wait time before and make sure that element is present

Comment: Not work , It shows Exception "Element should have been "select" but was input". This is because my actual web control is INPUT tag and Select is use for DropDown.

Comment: Updated my answer.. check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
Select obj = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("comobobox-2006-inputE!")));
```

1. `obj.selectByVisibleText("EQUALS");`
2. `obj.selectByIndex(0);`
3. `obj.selectByValue("eq");`

choose anyone & let me know, if this help you.
And change find element locator selection option if find by id is not helpful for you. Use xpath instead of id.

Comment: Not working. Also try with other id, xpath and cssselector  option. but no luck.